# C# to JavaScript real time/date conversion

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have this code in C# that generates an result below each time the browser is loaded.

```
C#

Double ValorGerado = 40.1714444;
Double Co2 = 13.1254644;

TimeSpan final = DateTime.Now.Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + " 00:00"));

this.lblGeracao.Text = String.Format("{0:#,##0}", (Convert.ToDecimal(ValorGerado * final.TotalSeconds))) + "*";

this.lblCO2.Text = String.Format("{0:#,##0}", ((Convert.ToInt32(Co2 * final.TotalSeconds) / 1000))) + "**";
```

Result:

-- We have generate 75,070,550 kWh * 
Clean Energy in 2013.

-- This means that we stop emitting 24,528 ** g of CO2 in the atmosphere.

---

How can I'm get that result in real time with javaScript? how could it do that?

I started doing something like this:

```
JS
var ValorGerado = 40.1714444; 
var Co2 = 13.1254644; 


var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; 
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();        
var curr_seconds = d.getSeconds();


setInterval(function() {

$('.Timer').text((new Date) * ValorGerado);

}, 1);
```

And the HTML

```
HTML
<div class="Timer" style="width:100%;"></div>
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Here is a example somthing very similar: http://opower.com/

Comment: Well you are not calculating the date difference... `(new Date() - d)` which gives you milliseconds.

Comment: You are looking for [Date.getTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hcawkw2%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) method... and [calculating elapsed time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee532932%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

Comment: Hey Alexei, thanks, but I'm dont know how.

Comment: Here is a example somthing very similar: [link](http://opower.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var yearStart = new Date((new Date()).getFullYear(),0,1),
    ValorGerado = 40.1714444,
    Co2 = 13.1254644; 

Number.prototype.toNormalString = String.prototype.toNormalString || function(){
    return this.toString().split('.')[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

setInterval(function(){
    var secondsElapsed = (new Date()).getTime() - yearStart.getTime();    
    $('.geracaoValue').text(secondsElapsed * ValorGerado);       
    $('.co2Value').text(((secondsElapsed * Co2) / 1000).toNormalString());
}, 30);
```

It could probably be done a little cleaner, but I tried to emulate the C# method. If you want to format the string with no decimal and add commas use Number.toNormalString . The example has one value each way.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MQZUB/3/

**Update:** I realized extending the Number object instead of the String object was much cleaner.

Comment: Yes, thanks, very close, how to concatenate same as that: 75,070,550 kWh and 24,528? any idea?

Comment: You can concat any string to the result of toNormalString() with the '+' operator. However, I don't recommend mixing formatting and functional code on that level. Here is an edited fiddle as per your example: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/MQZUB/4/)